# Creating a justified, equally spaced navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I was browsing a few pages here and found something that almost worked for my needs, which was to have a navbar on a webpage with all the links equally spaced from each other, as if justified, and having an 8% padding on the left and right, so that the background of the navbar spans the width of the page, but the  containing the links does not exceed the 8% limitation.

I don't have the code since I deleted it and went for another design a while ago, but since I want to revisit the idea, I'm hoping someone could offer me a solution. The method I used before involved sticking an empty  under the navbar with a width set, but a height of 0. However, even with the height at 0, I still ended up with a navbar that had extra space underneath, taking up some amount of height, and ruining the symmetry that most navbars have above and below. To provide an example, the excessive space I'm referring to is the green bit here:

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. Can you reformulate your question and make it more clear?

Comment: Could you recreate the code?  More than likely, it is a margin or padding you forgot about, but without code we will be unable to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this article is what you're looking for:

http://code.jelmerdemaat.nl/2012/perfectly-justified-css-grid-technique-using-inline-block/

In brief, you'll want your code to look something like this:

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 550px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.wrapper div{
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper div:first-child {
    padding-left: 8%;
}

.wrapper div:last-child {
    padding-right: 8%;
}

.wrapper:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Only to see effect better */
body{ margin: 0; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;}
.wrapper,.wrapper div{ padding: 5px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
  <div>This can be anything.</div>
</div>
```

The magic is in the .wrapper:after portion of the code, which makes the align justify kick in and do its stuff.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrT9T/

Comment: Perfect! I actually tried that :after thing once, but I never got it to work. I must have been doing something horrendously wrong. In any case, the link had what I needed, and after a bit of fiddling around with the code, I've managed to adapt it to my needs by adding the left-right padding of 8% and a width of 84% to the wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

Codrops did a post on a fully justified (and vertically centered) header that might fit your needs.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/14/justified-and-vertically-centered-header-elements/

I've never heard of this 8% trick so I can't help you with that specific implementation of a fully justified header.

Comment: The 8% thing is just so that there is a space on the left and right of the page. I put it on all my main divs so that the pages dont completely stretch from left to right, making it harder for visitors to read long lengths of text.